# Read first 100 rows from Parquet file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parquet, parquet.net

I have these huge parquet files, stored in a blob, with more than 600k rows and I'd like to retrieve the first 100 so I can send them to my client app. This is the code I use now for this functionality:

```
private async Task < Table > getParquetAsTable(BlobClient blob) {
  var table = new Table();
  using(var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync()) {
    using(var memory = new MemoryStream()) {
      await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
      var parquetReader = new ParquetReader(memory);

      table = parquetReader.ReadAsTable();
    }
  }
  var first100 = table.Take(100);
}
```

However, this process is kind of slow. `await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);` takes 20 seconds and `table = parquetReader.ReadAsTable();` takes 15 more so totally I have to wait 35  seconds.

Is there a way to limit this stream and get the first 100 rows at once, without having to download all of the rows, format them with `ReadAsTable` and then take the first 100 only?

Comment: Read rows one by one up to 100.

Comment: How can I achieve that, I googled reading row by row parquets in c# but couldn't find any examples..

Comment: The "[reading files](https://github.com/elastacloud/parquet-dotnet#reading-files)" example demonstrates opening a file as a `Stream` type then feeding that directly to a `ParquetReader` constructor. Therefore, you should be able to save 20 seconds by skipping the copy to a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score -1):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.Parquet/) - an open source library, you can stream Parquet file as below. (uses Parquet.net under the hood.)

Install Nuget package

> install-package ChoETL.Parquet

Sample code

> using ChoETL;

```
using (var r = new ChoParquetReader(@"*** Your Parquet file ***")
    .ParquetOptions(o => o.TreatByteArrayAsString = true)
    )
{
     var dt = r.Take(100).AsDataTable();
}
```

For more information, please visit [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5270332/Cinchoo-ETL-Parquet-Reader) article.