# R: Reading first n rows from parquet file?

Tags: r, parquet

I realise parquet is a column format, but with large files, sometimes you don't want to read it all to memory in R before filtering, and the first 1000 or so rows may be enough for testing. I don't see an option in the read parquet documentation [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/read_parquet.html).

I see a solution for pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982871/pandas-reading-first-n-rows-from-parquet-file/69888274#69888274), and an option for c# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69481001/4927395), both of which are not obvious to me how they might translate to R. Suggestions?

Comment: Looking through the docs, it seems like arrow gives lazy evaluation. So maybe you can `dplyr::slice_head(n=1000) %>% compute()`?

Comment: Unfortunately `arrow::read_parquet()` does not appear to use lazy evaluation, based on my testing of the time and max memory use to a) read all the file, versus b) a piped implementation of `slice()` as you proposed. - both delivery similar results.

Comment: I think if you use `arrow::open_dataset()` that will index the parquet dataset and set it up for lazy evaluation. More here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html

Comment: @Jon is correct, `arrow::open_dataset()` appears to allow lazy evaluation. The lazy object is not compatible with `slice()` , but `head()` or `filter()` works. A good result - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Jon and Dan for pointing in the right direction.

`arrow::open_dataset()` allows lazy evaluation (docs [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html)), which you can then get the `head()` from (but not `slice()`), or `filter()`. This process is faster, and uses much less peak ram. Example below.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73131505/r-reading-first-n-rows-from-parquet-file

library(dplyr)
library(arrow)
library(tictoc) # optional, used to time results

tic("read all of large parquet file")
my_animals <- read_parquet("data/my_animals.parquet")
toc() # slow and uses heaps of ram

tic("read parquet and write mini version")
my_animals <- open_dataset("data/my_animals.parquet") 
my_animals # this is a lazy object

my_animals %>% 
  #slice(1000L) %>% # doesn't work
  head(n=1000L) %>% 
  # filter(YEAROFBIRTH >= 2010) %>% # also works
  compute() %>% 
  write_parquet("data/my_animals_mini.parquet") # optional
toc() # much faster, much less peak ram used
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as_data_frame` argument of `read_parquet` to return the data as an 'Arrow Table' object. You can then use `{dplyr}` functions on this object, followed by `dplyr::collect` (`collect` will return the tibble object, whereas `compute` merely forces the computation).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)

my_animals <- read_parquet("data/my_animals.parquet", as_data_frame = FALSE) |>
  slice_head(n = 1000) |>
  collect()
```

This is readable, fast and memory efficient!

See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/data_wrangling.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I published this simple package for practical usage. https://github.com/mkparkin/Rinvent feel free to check if that can help.
There is a parameter called "sample" which brings sample rows. also it can read "delta" files as well

readparquetR(pathtoread="C:/users/...",
format="delta", sample=10)
or
readparquetR(pathtoread="C:/users/...",
format="parquet", sample=10)