# Working with big data sets in R with parquet

Tags: r, database, parquet

Currently I'm working with huge datasets to my computer in R (90 millions rows and 30 columns), however I just need to analyze a few columns and rows at the time and I need to make this in an efficient way.

My original data was in `dta` but I converted to `parquet` since consumes lower memory and time to read. Nevertheless, loading this datasets requieres a lot of RAM and time. In this post [R: Reading first n rows from parquet file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73131505/r-reading-first-n-rows-from-parquet-file) I found that it is possible to make certain operations faster by exploiting lazy evaluation with the function `arrow::open_dataset`. But I also found in the documentation that `arrow::read_parquet` can only select the desired columns with the parameter `col_select`, which makes faster the reading process. It is possible to combine this two techniques to make the process even more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here is a minimal reproducible example based on the built-in `airquality` dataset that combines `arrow::open_dataset()` with an on-the-fly selection of certain rows and columns to reduce overhead. See [Working with Arrow Datasets and dplyr](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/3.0/r/articles/dataset.html) for a more comprehensive overview.

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

## write sample .parquet data
dat = transform(
  airquality
  , Year = 1973
)

write_dataset(
  dat
  , path = "~/Downloads/airquality"
  , format = "parquet"
  , partitioning = c(
    "Year"
    , "Month"
  )
  , basename_template = "data-part-{i}.parquet"
  , existing_data_behavior = "overwrite"
  , compression = "gzip"
)

## read subset of rows and columns back into r
open_dataset(
  "~/Downloads/airquality"
) |> 
  # subset by rows
  filter(
    Month == 6L
  ) |> 
  # subset by columns
  select(
    Day
    , Temp
  ) |> 
  collect()
```